# Cassandra NoHostAvailableException caused by DriverException while traversing a resultset

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am getting this error repeatedly while traversing a resultset of size 100,000 . I have used

```
.withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000))
                .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(2000))
```

in my connector. Still i am getting this error.  Typically it fails after fetching 80000 rows.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.16.12.143:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out
>   waiting for server response), /172.16.12.141:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out
>   waiting for server response))     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:65)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:259)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:175)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
>     at
>   com.payu.merchantAnalytics.FunnelHourlyUtilCql.groupByHourCql(FunnelHourlyUtilCql.java:87)
>     at
>   com.payu.merchantAnalytics.FunnelHourlyUtilCql.main(FunnelHourlyUtilCql.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
>   Caused by:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /172.16.12.143:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out
>   waiting for server response), /172.16.12.141:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out
>   waiting for server response))     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:108)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$1.run(RequestHandler.java:179)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

**Solved** 
*Thanks* [Andy Tolbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4406006/andy-tolbert) for the answer. Setting the readTimeoutMillis using `SocketOptions.setReadTimeoutMillis(100000)` worked.

Now the code looks like :-

```
SocketOptions socketOptions = new SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(100000);
Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(nodes)
                .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000))
                .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(2000))
                .withSocketOptions(socketOptions)
                .withCredentials(username, password).build();
```

*Thanks A Lot :)*

Comment: What does your schema and query look like?   'Timed out waiting for server response' indicates that it took longer than SocketOptions.getReadTimeoutMillis() (default 12 seconds) for cassandra to respond to a request.

Comment: My query is actually scanning all the entries for a secondary index. This is a bad query i agree because it has to fetch a total of around 150,000 rows and it will involve a look up into every partition. But this query fetches all the rows without any problem . But fails after fetching 80,000 rows. 
Why do i have this problem with the driver only?
Should i try to change the  `SocketOptions.getReadTimeoutMillis()` value?

Comment: I mean  this query was fetching all the rows without any problem in cqlsh shell. Was giving the above error only in java driver. Anyways, `SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(someHighvalue)` did the trick.